# Can the parameter of prior probability depends on data?

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question, definition, bayesian

In Bayseian approach https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability we often use prior probability. Can we have a prior probability distribution with parameters and while estimating the posterior probability can I estimate the parameters of the prior from data?

Comment: Could you specify a bit further which posterior probability you are estimating, and with which prior probability and likelihood?

Comment: @mikkola It is a general question, no particular to a problem.

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15893).